# Is there a better way to repeat display multiple images in the same spot?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm creating a Minigame using Canvas HTML5 and am trying to display LEDs on top of another image, currently it works like this: [Image displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmALf.png)

Currently, the Image does display and change as intended however the function is not initialised straight away (i'm guessing this is due to Javascript running on one core and how the setInterval function works) the code also seems really clunky and long-winded.

Is there a better way to achieve looping of these images to form an animation?

I intend to add more animations as the minigame is 'idle' and ideally the function controlling the looping of images should be easily broken.

---

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawSafeBuster(imageSources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get number of images
    for (var src in imageSources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for (var src in imageSources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function () {
            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = imageSources[src];
    }
}

//Image path variables.
var imageSources = {
    ledPath: './graphics/leds_safe_dial_minigame.png'
};

drawSafeBuster(imageSources, function (images) {

    //Draw initial LED images.
    context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 2, 0, 115, 100, 850, 300, 120, 100);
    context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 2, 0, 115, 100, 1015, 300, 120, 100);

    //LED Animation Loop
    var ledRepeat = setInterval(function () {
        context.fillStyle = '#999999';

        var ledRepeat1 = setInterval(function () {
            context.fillRect(850, 300, 120, 45);
            context.fillRect(1015, 300, 120, 45);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 2, 0, 115, 100, 850, 300, 120, 100);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 2, 0, 115, 100, 1015, 300, 120, 100);
        }, 500);

        var ledRepeat2 = setInterval(function () {
            context.fillRect(850, 300, 120, 45);
            context.fillRect(1015, 300, 120, 45);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 120, 0, 115, 100, 850, 300, 120, 100);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 120, 0, 115, 100, 1015, 300, 120, 100);
        }, 1500);

        var ledRepeat3 = setInterval(function () {
            context.fillRect(850, 300, 120, 45);
            context.fillRect(1015, 300, 120, 45);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 238, 0, 115, 100, 850, 300, 120, 100);
            context.drawImage(images.ledPath, 238, 0, 115, 100, 1015, 300, 120, 100);
        }, 2500);

        var clearInterval = setInterval(function () {

            clearInterval(ledRepeat1);
            clearInterval(ledRepeat2);
            clearInterval(ledRepeat3);
        }, 3500);

    }, 4500);

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making each LED an object with its own state (on/off). Create a game object to track the game state and current time/tick. (Here's some light reading about [game loops](http://%20https://isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing))

Not sure about your exact requirements, but here's an example of how I would approach something similar. In the ideal world each requestAnimationFrame() is 1/60th of a second ~ 60 frames per second... See the above link for why this may not be case and how to correct for it.

I've not used images for LEDs but this could be added to the LED object and used in the draw function.

```js
let canvas, c, w, h,
  TWOPI = Math.PI * 2;

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
c = canvas.getContext('2d');
w = canvas.width = 600;
h = canvas.height = 400;

let game = {
  state: "RUNNING",
  tick: 0,
  actors: []
};

//LED object.
let LED = function(x, y, hue, radius, on, toggleRate) {
  this.position = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
  this.hue = hue;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.on = on;
  this.toggleRate = toggleRate;
  this.update = function(tick) {
    if (tick % this.toggleRate === 0) {
      this.on = !this.on;
    }
  };
  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, TWOPI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${this.hue}, ${this.on ? 80 : 20}%, ${this.on ? 70 : 30}%)`;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x + this.radius / 5, this.position.y - this.radius / 5, this.radius / 3, 0, TWOPI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${this.hue}, ${this.on ? 80 : 20}%, ${this.on ? 90 : 50}%)`;
    ctx.fill();
  };
}

//create LEDs
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  game.actors.push(
    new LED(
      100 + i * 25,
      100,
      i * 360 / 10,
      8,
      Math.random() * 1 > 0.5 ? true : false,
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 240) + 60
    )
  );
}

function update() {
  if (game.state === "RUNNING") {
    //increase game counter
    game.tick++;

    //update actors
    for (let a = 0; a < game.actors.length; a++) {
      game.actors[a].update(game.tick);
    }
  } else {
    //noop.
  }
}

function clear() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

function draw() {
  //draw all actors
  for (let a = 0; a < game.actors.length; a++) {
    game.actors[a].draw(c);
  }
}

function loop() {
  update();
  clear();
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (game.state === "RUNNING") {
    game.state = "PAUSED";
  } else {
    game.state = "RUNNING";
  }
  console.log(game.state);
});

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best quality always render to the canvas via `requestAnimationFrame`'s callback. Rendering using timers can result in flickering and or shearing of the animation.

`setTimeout` or `setInterval` are throttled by most browsers when the page is not in focus or visible. Nor are the callbacks always on time

If timing is important to 1/60th second use `performance.now` and the time argument passed to the `requestAnimationFrame` callback. You will never be precisely on time as the animation is only displayed every 1/60th second (16.66666...ms) so draw the next frame of the animation as soon as possible after the time required (see example)

From the information you gave in the question I could not workout what your animation looked like so I made something up as an example.

### Example

- Uses promise rather than callback when loading media
- Image has property added that represents the position of sub images (sprites). The function `drawSprite` takes the `imageName`, `spriteIdx`, and `locationName` to draw a sub image at a location on the canvas.
- The main render loop is the function `renderLoop` it waits until media is loaded and then uses the `timing` to do the animation.
- The array `timing` contains an object for each animation event. The object has the time offset of the event, the function to be called on that event, and the arguments passed to the function.
- The last timing object in this example, just resets the start time to repeat the animation.

Note that this example does not check if the browser stops the animation and will cycle through all animations to catch up.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
canvas.width = 64;
canvas.height = 16;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mediaLoaded = false;
const images = {};
var currentStage = 0;
var startTime;   // do not assign a value to this here or the animation may not start
loadMedia({ 
        leds: {
            src: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Iev.png",
            sprites: [
                {x: 0,  y: 0,  w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 0 red off
                {x: 16, y: 0,  w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 1 red on
                {x: 0,  y: 16, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 2 orange off
                {x: 16, y: 16, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 3 orange on
                {x: 0,  y: 32, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 4 green off
                {x: 16, y: 32, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 5 green on
                {x: 0,  y: 48, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 6 cyan off
                {x: 16, y: 48, w: 16, h: 16}, // idx 7 cyan on
            ]
        },
    }, images)
    .then(() => mediaLoaded = true);

const renderLocations = {
    a: {x: 0,  y: 0, w: 16, h: 16},
    b: {x: 16, y: 0, w: 16, h: 16},
    c: {x: 32, y: 0, w: 16, h: 16},
    d: {x: 48, y: 0, w: 16, h: 16},
};


function loadMedia(imageSources, images = {}) {
    return new Promise(allLoaded => {
        var count = 0;
        for (const [name, desc] of Object.entries(imageSources)) {
            const image = new Image;
            image.src = desc.src;
            image.addEventListener("load",() => {
                images[name] = image;
                if (desc.sprites) { image.sprites = desc.sprites }
                count --;
                if (!count) { allLoaded(images) }
            });
            count ++;
        }
    });
}

function drawSprite(imageName, spriteIdx, locName) {
    const loc = renderLocations[locName];
    const spr = images[imageName].sprites[spriteIdx];
    ctx.drawImage(images[imageName], spr.x, spr.y, spr.w, spr.h, loc.x, loc.y, loc.w, loc.h);
}
function drawLeds(sprites) {
    for(const spr of sprites) { drawSprite(...spr) }
}
function resetAnimation() {
    currentStage = 0;
    startTime += 4500;
}


const timing = [
    {time: 0,    func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 0, "a"], ["leds", 2, "b"], ["leds", 4, "c"], ["leds", 6, "d"]]]},
    {time: 500,  func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 1, "a"]]]},
    {time: 1500, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 0, "a"], ["leds", 3, "b"]]]},
    {time: 2000, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 1, "a"]]]},
    {time: 3000, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 0, "a"], ["leds", 2, "b"], ["leds", 5, "c"], ["leds", 7, "d"]]]},
    {time: 3250, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 1, "d"]]]},
    {time: 3500, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 3, "d"]]]},
    {time: 3750, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 5, "d"]]]},
    {time: 4000, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 7, "d"]]]},
    {time: 4250, func: drawLeds, args: [[["leds", 1, "d"]]]},
    {time: 4500 - 17, func: resetAnimation, args: []},
];
   
function renderLoop(time) {
    if (mediaLoaded) {
        if (startTime === undefined) { startTime = time }
        var offsetTime = time - startTime;
        const stage = timing[currentStage];
        if(offsetTime > stage.time) {
            currentStage++;
            stage.func(...stage.args);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Image used in example

[image: Color LEDs sprites On and Off]